# How is table cell height calculated?

Tags: html, css, rendering, html-table

After a couple of days spent struggling with HTML tables, my forehead has a grid of indents which incidentally are a mirror copy of my keyboard.

Speaking of grids, I'd like to know if there's any *set of rules* regarding `<td>` size.

Is it all according to the content? Is it affected by other cells in the same row? By the row itself? By the table? Plain ol' CSS?

NOTE: I'm specifically not looking for an answer to a specific question.
I just want to know how the darned height is *calculated* so I can figure out myself each time what to expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes table cells follows the content and it's siblings height.

You can say that it's a rectangle split in section, that no matter what it's inside it will always stay as a rectangle.

So even if you add a css height it will ignore it if the text is bigger than the css height.

So pretty much you can expect a dynamic height in most case scenarios.

But still...it should be used to show only tabular data and nothing else. For the rest there is `display:table-cell;`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/54nnj/) that you can play with.

Row styling doesn't work in this setting.

first td row: standard

second td row: given a height - note it affects the entire row

third td row: given padding, again affects entire row

fourth td row: given a large font

fifth td row: given large font and padding

CSS

```
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td {
    height: 50px;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child {
    padding: 10px;
}
table tr:nth-child(4) td:first-child{
    font-size: 34px;
}
table tr:nth-child(5) td:first-child{
    font-size: 34px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

PS - Use tables only for "TABULAR" data.